# How to find this Select Option using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I found this COLDFUSION code for a Select List to automatically check a list for a value and if not there set "the default" to selected.  Only it doesn't work for me.
It gets into the cfif, and the Script is being put into the page, however it never finds the JQUERY SELECTOR for default to mark it as SELECTED.

`#igShutdownTimer option[default="default"]` does not mark `value="60"` as selected when the page first runs like I thought it should.

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <label for="igShutdownTimer">Ignition ShutDown Timer:</label>
    <cfset pos = listfind(inputList,"1_uint ")>
    <cfif not pos>
        <script>
            $('##igShutdownTimer option[default="default"]').attr('selected','selected');
        </script>
    </cfif>
    <select form="configDetail" id="igShutdownTimer" name="1_uint" class="form-control" changeName="Ignition ShutDown Timer">
        <option value="0" <cfif pos and getParams.value[pos] is "0">selected</cfif>>0 Minutes</option>
        <option value="10" <cfif pos and getParams.value[pos] is "10">selected</cfif>>10 Minutes</option>
        <option value="20" <cfif pos and getParams.value[pos] is "20">selected</cfif>>20 minutes</option>
        <option value="30" <cfif pos and getParams.value[pos] is "30">selected</cfif>>30 Minutes</option>
        <option value="40" <cfif pos and getParams.value[pos] is "40">selected</cfif>>40 Minutes</option>
        <option value="50" <cfif pos and getParams.value[pos] is "50">selected</cfif>>50 Minutes</option>
        <option value="60" <cfif pos and getParams.value[pos] is "60">selected</cfif>  default="default">1 Hour</option>
        <option value="120" <cfif pos and getParams.value[pos] is "120">selected</cfif>>2 hours</option>
        <option value="240" <cfif pos and getParams.value[pos] is "240">selected</cfif>>4 Hours</option>
        <option value="480" <cfif pos and getParams.value[pos] is "480">selected</cfif>>8 Hours</option>
        <option value="720" <cfif pos and getParams.value[pos] is "720">selected</cfif>>12 hours</option>
        <option value="1440" <cfif pos and getParams.value[pos] is "1440">selected</cfif>>24 Hours</option>
        <option value="4294967295" <cfif pos and getParams.value[pos] is "4294967295">selected</cfif>>Unlimited</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

This is what gets printed to the source and as you can see SELECTED does not show up for Default.

```
<script>
    $('#igShutdownTimer option[default="default"]').attr('selected','selected');
</script>
<select form="configDetail" id="igShutdownTimer" name="9X26889E92489D" class="form-control" changeName="Ignition ShutDown Timer">
    <option value="0" >0 Minutes</option>
    <option value="10" >10 Minutes</option>
    <option value="20" >20 minutes</option>
    <option value="30" >30 Minutes</option>
    <option value="40" >40 Minutes</option>
    <option value="50" >50 Minutes</option>
    <option value="60" default="default">1 Hour</option>
    <option value="120" >2 hours</option>
    <option value="240" >4 Hours</option>
    <option value="480" >8 Hours</option>
    <option value="720" >12 hours</option>
    <option value="1440" >24 Hours</option>
    <option value="4294967295" >Unlimited</option>
</select>
```

Can someone help me with the necessary selector to find `<option value="60" default="default">1 Hour</option>` in this list and any other list that `default="default"` might show up in.

---

Working code After Rory's Answer:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <label for="igShutdownTimer">Ignition ShutDown Timer:</label>
    <cfset pos = listfind(inputList,"1_uint ")>
    <select form="configDetail" id="igShutdownTimer" name="#daCFC.enc('1_uint')#" class="form-control" changeName="Ignition ShutDown Timer">
        <option value="0" <cfif pos and getParams.value[pos] is "0">selected</cfif>>0 Minutes</option>
        <option value="10" <cfif pos and getParams.value[pos] is "10">selected</cfif>>10 Minutes</option>
        <option value="20" <cfif pos and getParams.value[pos] is "20">selected</cfif>>20 minutes</option>
        <option value="30" <cfif pos and getParams.value[pos] is "30">selected</cfif>>30 Minutes</option>
        <option value="40" <cfif pos and getParams.value[pos] is "40">selected</cfif>>40 Minutes</option>
        <option value="50" <cfif pos and getParams.value[pos] is "50">selected</cfif>>50 Minutes</option>
        <option value="60" class="default" <cfif pos and getParams.value[pos] is "60">selected</cfif>>1 Hour</option>
        <option value="120" <cfif pos and getParams.value[pos] is "120">selected</cfif>>2 hours</option>
        <option value="240" <cfif pos and getParams.value[pos] is "240">selected</cfif>>4 Hours</option>
        <option value="480" <cfif pos and getParams.value[pos] is "480">selected</cfif>>8 Hours</option>
        <option value="720" <cfif pos and getParams.value[pos] is "720">selected</cfif>>12 hours</option>
        <option value="1440" <cfif pos and getParams.value[pos] is "1440">selected</cfif>>24 Hours</option>
        <option value="4294967295" <cfif pos and getParams.value[pos] is "4294967295">selected</cfif>>Unlimited</option>
    </select>
</div>
<cfif not pos>
    <script>
        $('##igShutdownTimer option.default').prop('selected', true);
    </script>
</cfif>
```

Comment: Should probably be using .prop('selected', true) instead of .attr('selected','selected') ... but jQuery can't seem to make up their minds about this anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put your code in a document.ready handler so that it gets executed when the DOM has loaded. Currently your `script` block is being executed *before* the `select element exists in the page:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#igShutdownTimer option[default="default"]').attr('selected','selected');
    });
</script>
```

That said it would be much better practice to use `prop()` over `attr()` and also to select the default `option` using a class, as creating your own non-standard attributes will mean your HTML is invalid. Something like this:

```
<select form="configDetail" id="igShutdownTimer" name="9X26889E92489D" class="form-control">
    <option value="0">0 Minutes</option>
    <!-- other options... -->
    <option value="60" class="default">1 Hour</option>
</select>
```

```js
$(function() {
    $('#igShutdownTimer option.default').prop('selected', true);
});
```

Comment: cheap man's version: swap the position of the <select> tag and the <cfif> tag

Comment: I implemented everything you mentioned including putting the cfif script underneath the div to be executed after the selects where  in the DOM instead of before the elements where in the DOM